# Login in django failing after adding css to login page

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms, django-login

I have a basic django website running on a postgres database.

The login page code was structured as follows,

```
{% extends "_base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block title %}Log In{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
<h2>Log In</h2>
<div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-4">
            <form method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form | crispy }}
                <button class="btn btn-primary " type="submit">Log In</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

and _base.html as

```
<!-- additional css content for navbar -->
        <div class="container-fluid full-height p-0">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock content %}
<!-- similar footer content -->
```

And then I decided to add some css from the bootstrap in the form of a just so my login page would look cleaner. Therefore I added some css in this form.

```
{% extends "_base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block title %}Log In{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
<div class="bg-dark vh-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-3 p-5 border bg-light rounded-2">
        <h2>Log In</h2>
        <form method=" post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form | crispy }}
            <button class="btn btn-primary " type="submit">Log In</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

with _base.html as follows

```
        <div class="container-fluid p-0">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock content %}
        </div>
```

As you can see my I haven't touched the form "component". Why is the form not working?
*Note: I have configured my static files properly, i.e directories mentioned in settings.py*

I had setup to redirect to the home page, but the link that is getting passed in to the url is:

```
http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=XgEmrXg1fMJfOoPSnDyuY733MrWTxjaAWHnCnej9sFI6buue93sMgggrwIsTOibd&login=adminsav%40email.com&password=testpass123
```

Comment: Try removing the space in your form tag method - `method="post"`

Comment: That actually worked, damn I actually didn't see that, thank you!